# Woocommerce set billing field value equal to other billing field value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want the billing field 'company email' to be equal to Billing E-mail address.

I thought this would work but I only get an empty field:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', 'custom_admin_billing_fields', 10, 1 );
    function custom_admin_billing_fields( $billing_fields ) {
        $billing_fields['tlr_company_email']['value'] = $billing_fields['email']['value'];
        return $billing_fields;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Need some more background. 1) When do you want it to be equal? on the checkout or only on the admin page? 2) how did you created the company email address, can you share the code? 3) Do you wish it to be overwritten everytime you save the billing address?

Comment: The fields are generated by the plugin 'Teamleader for Woocommerce', a plugin that sends the order data to Teamleader to make an invoice. The fields that are already filled in are filled in when placing an order trough the normal checkout proces. The empty fields need to be the same as the filled in ones that's why I want the fields to be equal (Company email = e-mailadres, company phone = telefoon, company adres = Adresregel 1, ...). Because now you just have to copy everything and I want it to do that automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the proper way of doing it is to update once the payment is completed, after the checkout. The following code is hooked to the payment complete trigger. It will copy the billing email to the custom company billing email.

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'replicate_billing_email', 100, 1);

function replicate_billing_email($order_id){
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id); //obatin the completed order as object
    $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email(); //get the billing email address
    update_post_meta($order_id, 'tlr_company_email', $billing_email); //update the company email
    update_post_meta($order_id, '_tlr_company_email', $billing_email); //it maybe saved like that, with underscore, ommit if not needed
}
```

To test it, complete a test order.

Comment: With a couple of modifications to your code it worked, thanks! I still need to get the value of a custom field I generated with the plugin Woocommerce checkout manager. This fields is displayed under the billing details on the order edit page, so it's not an input field. I can't get the value on the same way I did for the other input fields. Any idea how I can get the value of that?